# Converter busca com PyMongo: Dicionário em JSON

Tags: json, python, python-3.x, mongodb

Estou usando PyMongo para fazer uma busca:

```
resultado = db.find_one({'nome':'xpto'})
```

O resultado desta busca é um dicionário em Python, mas eu preciso convertê-lo para um JSON. Qual a melhor forma de fazê-lo?

Answer (score 3):

A Standard Library do python fornece o módulo **json**, responsável por realizar a conversão de dict para json e vice-versa.

O código ficaria desta forma:

```
import json
resultado = db.find_one({'nome':'xpto'})
resultadoJson = json.dumps(resultado) #Convertendo dict para json
```

[Mais informações sobre o módulo json.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html)

Answer (score 2):

O próprio PyMongo disponibiliza uma biblioteca para lidar com esta situação: **bson.json_util**

A solução seria a seguinte:

```
from bson.json_util import dumps
resultado_json = dumps(resultado)
```